# Conditional in Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I am trying to perform a classification in Arcmap's raster calculator, but it seems that the use of multiple conditional is confusing me. What am I doing wrong in the following con-statement?:

```
Con("raster" < 1,0.5, Con("raster" >= 1,1.5 & Con("raster" < 15,1.5, Con("raster" > 15,2.0))))
```

Comment: Can't test this but perhaps something like `Con("raster" < 1, 0.5, Con("raster" >= 1 & "raster" < 15, 1.5, 2.0))`?

Comment: Yes, I think that approach is the way to go. Adding three con, is just confusing. The last ,2.0 will possibly do the trick.